# An error occur during executing my program that EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled see innerException for Details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to connect my MVC application with SQL server. but when i execute the program that time i am getting an error

The description of error is

> *An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command
>   definition*

Here is a code

```
public class EmployeeDataController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Details( int d)
        {
            EmployeeDataContext edc = new EmployeeDataContext();
           EmployeeData employee=  edc.employeedata.Single(x => x.id==d);


    return View(employee);
```

The error occur at

```
EmployeeData employee=  edc.employeedata.Single(x => x.id==d);
```

I would really appreciate some guidance in this regard.

Comment: `EmployeeData employee=  edc.employeedata.Single(x => x.id==d).FirstOrDefault();` Try this code

Comment: Yep thank you Mr Gonul.I get it

Comment: Actually, I am using a table that contain id, name, gender and location are parameters. but instead of using location parameter in a detail. chtml, I was using the city as a parameter. That's why I am getting this error. But now I have corrected it and solve the problem